# Docker build centos:6.4 gives manifest for centos:6.4 not found error on Ubuntu 22

Tags: docker, centos, manifest, docker-build

I'm new to Docker, and got a project that with following content in the Dockerfile

```
from    centos:6.4
run     rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
run     rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
#there are more lines..
```

When I try to build the image with following

```
sudo docker build -t test .
```

I get following result;

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.656kB
Step 1/22 : from    centos:6.4
manifest for centos:6.4 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

I can see there is a version specified in the file in https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS6.4

but not sure why the manifest unknown message appears.

Any help would be highly appreciated to identify and resolve this issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to use dead things ?   CentOS 6 is EOL for a while.

Comment: @Remi Collet but the project developed many years ago by another developer, and I received it to maintain. No information received from the original developer.

Comment: You can look https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/tags?page=1, find centos:centos6, centos:centos6.6,centos:centos6.7,centos:centos6.8,centos:centos6.9,centos:centos6.10. No 6.4, so please choose a existing version.

Comment: @life888888 already tried 6.6 but it looks things in the project are very version specific and produces more errors

Comment: Create a VM , and install CentOS 6.4 from CD ISO, but another problem, is any centos 6.4 update repo is existing ?